# UI not updating when mdDialog calls parent controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, mddialog

Hi Im having an issue where im showing a mdDialog from Angular Material and using my directives controller as the controller of the dialog so i can call a specific function without having to pass stuff back and add in extra steps to the code. The function gets called successfully but the UI is not updated when the function successfully ends. Wondering if anyone can see where im going wrong with this.

Assume for now that the first if statement is true.

**Dialog call**

```
this.showImageUploadModal = function() {
  $mdDialog.show({
      clickOutsideToClose: true,
      scope: $scope,        // use parent scope in template
      preserveScope: true,  // do not forget this if use parent scope
      templateUrl: 'app/directives/modals/upload-files-modal.html',
      controller: MessagingController,
      controllerAs: 'controller'
      });
};
```

**Function being called but not updating UI**

```
this.addAttachment = function() {
  console.log("sending attachment");
  var ref = this;
  var note = this.user.first_name + " has attached a file.";

  if($state.current.name === 'inbox') {
    MessagingService.createMessage(this.convo.id, note, this.userUploadedNoteFiles).then(
      function success(response) {
        console.log("Inbox attachment sent", response);
        ref.convo.messages.push(response.data);
        console.log(ref.convo.messages);
        // ref.viewableNoteFiles = [];
      },
      function failure(response) {
        $mdToast.show(
          $mdToast.simple().
          textContent("Failed to send the message please try again.").
          theme('error-toast'));
      }
    );
  } else if (this.notes === 'true') {
    TicketingService.addNote($stateParams.id, note, this.userUploadedNoteFiles).then(
      function success(response) {
        console.log("Notes attachment sent", response);
        ref.convo.messages.push(response.data);
        // ref.viewableNoteFiles = [];
      },
      function failure(response) {
        $mdToast.show(
          $mdToast.simple().
          textContent("Failed to send the message please try again.").
          theme('error-toast'));
      }
    );
  } else if(this.contractor === 'true') {
    TicketingService.createMessage($stateParams.id, this.convo.id, note, this.userUploadedNoteFiles).then(
    function success (response) {
        console.log("Contractor attachment sent", response);
        ref.convo.messages.push(response.data);
    },
    function failure () {
      $mdToast.show(
        $mdToast.simple().
        textContent("Failed to upload the file attachments").
        theme('error-toast'));
    }
  );
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end i found i could achieve what i was looking for using Angulars $rootScope.$broadcast. to broadcast the return data back to the controller that needed it.

Im not sure this is the right way to do it but it works.